# Can I use a dedicated desktop GPU with a USB-C docking station?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

I am not asking for a KVM switch or anything like that, as this similar question does: [How to share/switch several devices between two PCs when KVM switches have limited ports?](https://superuser.com/questions/1632454/how-to-share-switch-several-devices-between-two-pcs-when-kvm-switches-have-limit).

My question is purely hypothetical as I do not have a desktop PC, neither a dedicated GPU, as provided in the example below but only a laptop that works perfectly well with my current setup (a USB-C docking station with two monitors and peripherals).

I was wondering if I could use a dedicated GPU (say a RTX 3060) in a desktop PC if I connected the docking station as it is. I am not sure if I am thinking correctly, because the GPU has its own DP and HDMI ports and no USB-C port.

Would this mean that the GPU would be bypassed or would it work if the mainboard had a TB3 port? If so, would also it work if there was a dedicated TB3 card instead of the port on the mainboard itself, or is it just generally not possible?

Comment: No, at least not directly. You will be using the iGPU in the CPU when the monitor is connected to that, although I am not ruling out possibility to offload computation to the dedicated card.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when I use my laptop with the dedicated mobile GPU, it is also bypassed, if I don't use the HDMI or mDP port, but instead the USB-C port, even if it has the TB3 specification? Or is it entirelly different for laptops?

Comment: I think even on laptop, with the case of USB-C/TB3/TB4, you'll only be using the dedicated card in the manner of "computation offloading". I'm not entirely sure though since the wiring stuff *could* be a bit more "flexible" there, but I kinda doubt that the "provider" of the alt modes can be "outsourced" like that. Even if it's possible, it still depends on the design of the particular laptop, since the vendor may want to do it in the offloading way anyway for powersaving and so on.

Comment: For the record, that's already / at least the case before USB-C: there's no standard defining how / which GPU the internal screen and video output ports on laptops should be hooked up to respectively. Over the time quite a few quirky designs have been observed.